# If i was to write a script using sys functions but forget "import sys", what error would i get?

Tags: python-2.7, error-handling

i dont have any terminal to test this so its not possible to see what error would occur.
the question is a section of code in the form of a function. The question asks what error would occur if they ran the code and the first thing missing is the "import sys" command.

Comment: As you had internet access, you could have tried on https://www.python.org/shell/ or other equivalent places!

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we are using the function of any modules, which is not `imported` then it'll throw the error of unnamed function.

Answer to your question- below error will be prompted.

```
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
```